# parsing json array in django

Tags: android, django, json

Hi i am trying to parse JSON array in django sent from android 
the json response sent from android looks like

```
 [{"record":[{"intensity":"Low","body_subpart":"Scalp","symptom":"Agitation"}]}]
```

Now my function in django is as below :

```
record = simplejson.loads(request.POST['record'])
for o in record:            
    new_symptoms=UserSymptoms(health_record=new_healthrecord,body_subpart=o.body_subpart,symptoms=o.symptom,intensity=o.intensity)
    new_symptoms.save()
```

but its not working
gving me error 
For that i also tried to execute above lines in python shell

```
>>>rec=json.loads('[{"intensity":"Low","body_subpart":"Scalp","symptom":"Agitation"},{"intensity":"High","body_subpart":"Scalp","symptom":"Bleeding"}]')
>>> for o in rec:
...     print rec.body_subpart
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'body_subpart'
```

Comment: Why `rec.body_subpart` instead of `o.body_subpart`?

Comment: sorry typing mistake its o.body_subpart

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>rec=json.loads('[{"intensity":"Low","body_subpart":"Scalp","symptom":"Agitation"},{"intensity":"High","body_subpart":"Scalp","symptom":"Bleeding"}]')
>>> for o in rec:
...     print rec['body_subpart']
```

By default JSON object is transformed to Python `dict`, so it's surprising why you manage access its values this way:

```
record = simplejson.loads(request.POST['record'])
for o in record:            
    body_subpart=o.body_subpart
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `o['body_subpart']` instead of `o.body_subpart`. While this is the same in Javascript, it different in Python.